# Checking curl response code and returning results from inside a bash function

Tags: bash, curl, jq

I have a bash script that makes a ton of RESTful HTTP calls (via `curl`) to the many different endpoints of the same service. I want to write a bash function that makes a configurable curl request and verifies that the status is HTTP 200. If its not, the entire script should exit with an error code. If it is, the function should return the JSON that is returned by the HTTP response coming back from the REST API.

My best attempt thus far is:

```
function callServer() {

  payload=$1

  curl --request POST \
    --url https://myservice.example.com \
    --header 'Authorization: $API_KEY' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data '$payload' > jsonResp

}
```

An example usage from inside the script might be:

```
$getWidgetsJson=callServer '{"flim":"flam"}'
```

or:

```
$launchMissiles=callServer '{"fizz":"buzz","num":50}'
```

I think I'm close but having trouble seeing the forest through the trees here. How can I check 200-status on the response in the curl, and either fail the script or return the JSON from the function accordingly?

Comment: `curl` probably sets the exit code (`$?`) based on whether it was successful (200) or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

1. `--output` option to specify your output filename
2. `--write-out` option to get HTTP code response

Like this:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

function callServer() {

  local API_KEY="$1"
  local PAYLOAD="$2"
  local OUTPUT_FILENAME="$3"
  local -n HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE="$4"

  HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE=$(curl --request POST \
    --url https://myservice.example.com \
    --header "Authorization: ${API_KEY}" \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data "${PAYLOAD}" \
    --output "${OUTPUT_FILENAME}" \
    --write-out "%response_code" \
  )

}

declare HTTP_CODE=
callServer "theApikey" '{"flim":"flam"}' "theOutputFileName" HTTP_CODE

echo "The HTTP code is ${HTTP_CODE}"
echo "Filename content:"
cat theOutputFileName
echo "."
```

Comment: Thank @Arnaud (+1) - could I see a sample invocation of this `callServer` function? I'm wondering what it actually returns, and whether `--output jsonResp` means I need to save all the JSON results to an actual _file_ on my file system, or if both the JSON and the response code can somehow be returned together?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup I have updated my answer. Hope you now have a full answer

Comment: If you want to get HTTP code and JSON result you need to use a real file for the JSON result